# Setting HTML inside React from AJAX response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get some data and set a page to be the result

```
function getData() {
    $.ajax({
        url:"http://localhost:8080/",
        type:'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $('.App').html(data);
        }
    });
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    getData()
    return (
      <div className="App">This worked</div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is the response being printed out:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no"><meta name="theme-color" content="#000000"><link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"><link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico"><title>React App</title><link href="/static/css/main.c17080f1.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><div id="root"><div class="App" data-reactroot=""><header class="App-header"><img src="logo.svg" class="App-logo" alt="logo"/><h1 class="App-title">Welcome to React</h1></header><div></div></div></div><script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.d1b4ad06.js"></script></body></html>
```

When the page loads, it flashes the correct HTML for a second, then I get this error:

```
VM11047:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: there's nothing wrong with using jquery with react as long as you stay away from it's dom manipulation methods such as `.html()` (which makes up most of the library). You should instead be updating data that causes the react component to render said data once available.

Answer (score 1):

You could use react's dangerouslySetInnerHTML prop, more info here https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html

or the safer way to handle is to return a json response and create components to display that returned data

there is also an interesting article on why not to mix jquery dom manipulation and react.
http://tech.oyster.com/using-react-and-jquery-together/